# Get non-system running package name

Tags: android

I want to have a list of non-system running process (to kill // Please don't call police!). But I just know how to get a non-system package list and a running process list. Just like this:

```
\\----non-system app
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : installedApplications)
            {
                if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                    sb.append("Package name : " + appInfo.packageName + "\n");
                }
            }

 \\----running process
for (AndroidAppProcess process : processes) {
                sb.append(process.name +"\n");
            }
```

I want to have a kind of "mixed" list to get non-system running process. So please help me.

And if you asked, I'm using *'com.jaredrummler:android-processes:1.0.1'* to get process 'cause it doesn't need permission.

Comment: Killing processes on Android is bad. Let the system work the way it's intended to.

Comment: @Karakuri i know that. But that's not the point of this question, bro